# Map different paths to separate websites

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

Running on IIS 8.5, I have 4 different sites running asp.net applications, let's say a:80, b:7777, c:8888 and d:9999 (all running on different ports)

Is there a way to have domain.com point to default web site a and the 3 other apps -> domain.com/a (point to a:7777), domain.com/b (point to b:8888) and domain.com/c (point to c:9999) and all 4 have separate app pools?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Typically what you're asking for is achieved by using a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in front of the sites. Some popular dedicated options include [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) and [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

It also appears that IIS by itself can potentially do it with the URL Rewrite module. Here's a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) with more info:

> There are times when you need to reverse proxy through a server. The most common example is when you have an internal web server that isn’t exposed to the internet, and you have a public web server accessible to the internet. If you want to serve up traffic from the internal web server, you can do this through the public web server by creating a tunnel (aka reverse proxy).
>
> Essentially, you can front the internal web server with a friendly URL, even hiding custom ports.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add each asp.net website as an "Application" on the the same website.  Run up IIS Manager (inetmgr), right-click on the website and select "Add Application".  You'll be prompted to fill in all the standard info like you would a website (App Pool, path, security context, etc). The important part is the "Alias" - whatever you type here becomes the "b" in "domain.com/b".  The only catch about doing this is that you will need to ensure your website has been coded to assume current-path-relative references to files.  So, when the HTML makes reference to your JS, CSS and images, they're all href="images/logo.png" instead of root-path-relative, being href="/images/logo.png" - this is because you're not hosting the website in the root path.

Comment: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application